# ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.PHONE5'

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I wrote a trigger for validating phone number in oracle 10g as shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PHONE5
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF PHONE ON HR.TR
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

  IF(LENGTH(:NEW.PHONE)>10)
  OR (LENGTH(:NEW.PHONE)<10)) THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'PHONE NUMBER SHOULD CONSIST OF 10 DIGITS');
  END IF;

END;
```

I got error as ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.PHONE5'
I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is a horrible use for a trigger. The correct way to enforce such a rule is a check constraint: `alter table tr add constraint phone_length_ck check (length(phone) = 10);`. No doubt this is a homework assignment mandating the use of a trigger, but in real life this would fail a code review.

Answer (score 2):

You have have some syntax errors on adding a bunch of extra parenthesis.
Also you can remove the redundant parenthesis for `IF`. Check the code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PHONE5
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  OF PHONE ON HR.TR
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF LENGTH(:NEW.PHONE) > 10 OR LENGTH(:NEW.PHONE) < 10 THEN 
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'PHONE NUMBER SHOULD CONSIST OF 10 DIGITS');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Sir/Ma'am, Just now I executed code, but still I am getting error:                                                                 Dec 04, 2019 4:41:51 AM Login_Systems.Trigger ADDActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: PHONE NUMBER SHOULD CONSIST OF 10 DIGITS
ORA-06512: at "HR.PHONE5", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.PHONE5'

Comment: `ORA-20000: PHONE NUMBER SHOULD CONSIST OF 10 DIGITS` is the error raised by your trigger when the entered phone number is not ten digits long. In other words, this seems to be your trigger working **as you designed it**. If you're still not happy please extend your answer with the input data which is causing this error when you think it shouldn't.

Comment: This means the code is working because you are receiving the error you are raising.